# Is the hole cut in the wall for externally vented, over stove microwaves, standard?

Tags: exhaust-vent, microwave-oven

I have a Goldstar MV-1515W microwave installed over the stove vented externally. I want to replace it. Goldstar became LG. I contacted LG and they were unable to tell me whether a new model will have the hole in the wall, in the same place. I am unable to find the template used many years ago to cut the hole and hang the microwave. If I had the template I could compare that to new models.

Is there any standardization with regard to the hole for externally vented microwaves?

Answer (score 2):

Nope there is no standard for exhausted hoods as far as location some are vented backside and some topside and others can do both.  But as far as the hole location I would measure exactly where it is on the original unit then pull up the specifications sheets at the manufacturers website for any new model you plan to buy.

Comment: Yes, I can take the microwave out, measure where the hole is, then go to the store and see what may be compatible. Very simple suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Measure the unit and the wall and the specs will be located by the product on the sellers website I'm sure instead of driving that would be easier.